# Is it possible to treat $_POST like single quotes rather the double quotes?

Tags: php, validation, security, post

I have a `$_POST` field called `password` which holds the password posted form an HTML form. The first two checks it goes through are:

```
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
if(strlen($_POST['password'])>=8){
```

The problem is that if the post include a dollar sign `($)` then everything behind it including the dollar sign is ignored. I can see this because if something such as `odte$tPa55word` is posted the `strlen` only returns `4`. I think this is because the `$_POST['password']` treats the contents like double quote string `("")` rather the single quote `('')` which means everything after the $ is interpreted as a variable.

I have found one solution to this which is to `addcslashes()` but the problem is that I have no Idea if the `preg_match` that follows ignores these slashes or if it will respond to them.

The question is if there is some way to treat `$_POST` variables like single quote strings rater then double quote stings to make the inputs more secure and if this is not possible then what kind of escape statement should I use to make thing like this not occur ?

EDIT

Full code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['password'])){
        if(strlen($_POST['password'])>=8){
            if($_POST['password']===$_POST['passwordConfirm']){
                $password=password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            }
            else{
                echo('Err3');
            }
        }
        else{
            echo('Err1: '.strlen($_POST['password']));
        }
    }
    else{
        echo('Err0');
    }
?>
```

Request:

```
curl -v -d "password=odte$tPa55word" -w "\n" -X POST http://localhost:8888/test.php
```

This returns:

```
Err1: 4
```

Comment: Its not that, input values are treated as strings, they wont magically turn into php variables. https://3v4l.org/3KZRJ

Comment: So what is the reason that it ignores everything after and including the $ then ?

Comment: Because your trying to debug it wrong.

Comment: so how do I find what the problem is ? Maybe I can find it myself

Comment: Show all your code.

Comment: Told you so ;p Use `curl -v -d 'password=odte$tPa55word' -w "\n" -X POST http://localhost:80/test.php` instead.

Comment: The cmd will interpolate like php too..

Comment: Dammit XD Thanks for the help, I didn't think of looking for the problem there. Next time I'll know